# How to create sub-categories in Shopify?

Tags: html, css, shopify

I want to create subcategories in Shopify as the following:

/collection/sub-categories/sub-categories1/productName.

I already had a look at their documentation, but that isn't working since I have a lot of tags and all tags are appearing above the result page.

[Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/5yyodw)

Is there any way to create this and create the URL as I wanted?

Thanks!

Comment: [This is the method Shopify suggests for creating subcategories](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/collections/subcategories). If you've already tried this approach but it's not working, [it would be helpful if you could provide some extra information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on what you've tried so far, the specific problem and desired behaviour, and a snippet of your code where you think the issue might be.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that method. Problem is that using tags will result in lots of tags as I have around 200 products. What i need is to categories men wear and women wear and then further categories of those clothes.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify is very bad for multiple sub categories and listing depth of 2+.

This can help to an extent. Great video also to help

```
https://apps.shopify.com/uncomplicated-categories
```